# displaying records with a date at least one day greater then or = to today

Tags: sql

I have a field in a table called DATEF. It displays dates as follows: 2013-11-25 08:30:00.000. The field is used to show appointment dates. What I need to show are future appointment dates from today or = to today. (Getdate) for some reason this is not working for me today. Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... you're probably failing to factor in the time component. (This is for SQL Server, you'll have to find the equivalent for your respective environment)

```
SELECT <SOMETHING>
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEF >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```